# 1980-95 Ford Truck Power Steering hose seals

Tags: ford, power-steering, seal

When changing the power steering hoses on my Ford truck power steering, the new hoses come with a wide teflon seal pre-installed on both ends. These are one time non-reusable seals, so if you disconnect the line you must replace this seal. 
BUT, it seems all the 'replacement' seals sold at every parts store I have checked are 1/2 as wide as the one on the replacement hose ??
Perhaps the dealer ?

Comment: All Simular Power Steering Pump/hose 1987 Bronco, 1989 F150, 1990 F150, 1993 Areostar (except for rack & pinion)

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

The teflon seal has to be stretched to fit. You have to heat them in hot water and stretch them out some. I took a dowel and bevelled the end of it. Put the teflon seal on the end of it, then dunk it in hot water while working it up the bevel to get an even stretch. It takes a bit of work, but isn't that hard to make it happen.